Remote Desktop Web - Cert Error
I am getting a cert error when trying to open a browser based remote desktop session in my home lab.
The environment is Windows Server 2022 on VMWare ESXi 8.
I have a the following (pseudo) setup : remote.contoso.com which points to my Windows 2022 Server.
On the same LAN, but not domain joined I have a physical PC called WS01 that I would like to be able to RDP into via Windows-Server 2022 RD Gateway.
I have got as far as installing win-acme, getting a cert for remote.contoso.com and then installing the RDS HTML5 client.
Now from a public computer I can browse to https://remote.contoso.com/RDWeb/webclient/index.html and I get presented with a single personal resource (Desktop):

The issue is that when I try to open a connection to that resource I get the message :

The message is quite explicit - but the steps to get to the solution from here is not.
Some have suggested that my certificate should have a second domain name, the FQDN of my server - dc1.internal.contoso.com - but this would mean publishing my internal FQDN with a A record - that just doesn't seem right - or safe.
The browser itself loads https://remote.contoso.com/RDWeb/webclient/index.html with a valid certificate.
I also note that as a result of adding the Session Host via Powershell as documented in the instructions there is no collection listed in server manager.
Microsoft appears to have something to say about how to setup the certificates here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn781533(v=ws.11)#selecting-which-certificate-to-use (towards bottom of page)
I have no Calculator or any other default RD Web Apps.
How do I get this RD Web running?
How do I add other computers as a resource?
